# What is the word that means a query predicate can use an index

Tags: database-design, index, query

I remember reading in a paper a word that means “query predicate can be evaluated using an index” but I can’t recall the word. For example if you had a table with a column called “name” and you had an index on name, then a query that had a WHERE clause involving “name” could be succinctly described by this word as “An X-able query”, where X is the word I don’t remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "SARGable". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable):

> In relational databases, a condition (or predicate) in a query is said
> to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index to
> speed up the execution of the query. The term is derived from a
> contraction of Search ARGument ABLE.